# Array syntax in string: Uninitialized string offset error

Tags: php, string, random

I'm getting an unitialized string offset in the following code that was posted online:

```
function generateKey() {
    $length = 15;
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $string = '';
    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Is it because of $characters[] being applied to a string? I don't fully get what the error means, but how could I achieve the same effect and get around that (it's working fine right now, just throwing an error)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what has been already answered, but I suggest

- do the `strlen()` operation only once and store the maximum random number into a variable,
- initialize the `$string` buffer and write into it instead of an ongoing concatenation,
- decrease the counter `$p` so to work from back to front.

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/rmeuLPzZ), Code:

```
function generateKey() {
    $length = 15;
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $maxrnd = strlen($characters)-1;
    $string = str_repeat('0', $length);
    for ($p = $length; $p--;) {
        $string[$p] = $characters[mt_rand(0, $maxrnd)];
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this line to this:

```
$string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)-1)];
```

Note the `-1`.  [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) gives you the number of characters in the string, but they start at offset 0.

A string of `abc` has a length of 3, but the highest index I can use is `[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
```

If there are 10 characters in your string, strlen($characters) will return 10. However, your indexes will go from 0 to 9, so you have to subtract 1 from the strlen result.